# Pretty print django.db.models.JSONField in Django admin?

Tags: django

Django >= 3.1 supports a new [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField) model field. I am using one like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Example(models.Model):
    foobar = models.JSONField()
```

I've also included this model in Django's admin section. However, the field is just a simple textarea with the JSON included, not pretty printed.

How can I make sure the JSON displayed in Django's admin section is pretty printed, with indentation, like this:

```
{
  "example": {
     "a": 1,
     "b": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: I typed [django json widget](https://pypi.org/project/django-json-widget/) into a search engine.

Comment: @Melvyn Hi. That package is for the PostgreSQL JSONField, not for the generic django.db.models.JSONField released only in Django 3.1.

Comment: https://github.com/jmrivas86/django-json-widget/issues/44

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and found this post, where they use the [**pygments module**](https://pygments.org/): https://daniel.feldroy.com/posts/pretty-formatting-json-django-admin

```
import json
from django.contrib import admin
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import JsonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def pretty_json(self, instance):
        """Function to display pretty version of our data"""

        # Convert the data to sorted, indented JSON
        response = json.dumps(instance.metadata, sort_keys=True, indent=2) # <-- your field here

        # Truncate the data. Alter as needed
        response = response[:5000]

        # Get the Pygments formatter
        formatter = HtmlFormatter(style='colorful')

        # Highlight the data
        response = highlight(response, JsonLexer(), formatter)

        # Get the stylesheet
        style = "<style>" + formatter.get_style_defs() + "</style><br>"

        # Safe the output
        return mark_safe(style + response)

    pretty_json.short_description = 'Pretty json'
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a way to indent the JSON field without additional third party packages:

```
import json

from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin


class PrettyJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, *args, indent, sort_keys, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, indent=2, sort_keys=True, **kwargs)


class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    json_field = forms.JSONField(encoder=PrettyJSONEncoder)


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```

Comment: Tested and working on Django 4.0.5

Comment: Another way is to just `form.base_fields['my_json_field'].encoder = PrettyJSONEncoder` inside the `ModelAdmin.get_form` method.

Comment: Redefining the field in my case caused to lose the help text defined in the model. What I ended up doing was similar to what @toabi suggested, I did it in the `MyModelForm` `__init__`

`self.fields['json_field'].encoder = PrettyJSONEncoder`